# MySQL and PHP - Calculating price of product in DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, inventory

I am new to SQL and have been developing an inventory tracking system for a side business. I have developed it using PHP, MySQL and HTML. I have developed several features that will allow me to do some neat things. I have been stuck on figuring out how to calculate the price of a unit, made up of multiple components, once its assembled.

Currently, I have 2 tables that I hoped would help me come up with the final price figure.

## SQL Relationships

### Table 1: `Material_Inventory`

```
PRODUCT_ID (PK) | Quantity | Last Entry
```

This table helps me keep track of the quantity of each component in stock and keeps track of the last time a product was added

### Table 2: `Orders`

```
Order_ID |  Product_ID | Item_quantity | Unit_price
```

This table helps me track the unit price of each individual component per order. I same "per order" because the price of a component could differ from order to order.

## Problem

In trying to calculate the price of a finalized built unit (component a + component b + component c). I am having a difficult time figuring out how to calculate the final price. This is the issue I am running into:

- How can I account for price change of the components?
          - For example, I am about to assemble 2 units. But component A in                                         the first unit has a different unit price than component A in the second unit.

Any suggestion or any sort of feedback is greatly welcomed.

Thank you so much for your time!

cheers

Comment: isn't it as simple as getting all rows for a particular order, for each row calculate quantity * unit price, then total all rows? could probably be done with request.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean product price as FIFO methods (First In First Out) or Average? This is how you can calculate product price for Average Method :

```
select x.product_id, (x.total_price / x.total_quantity) as average_price
(
     Select a.product_id as product_id, 
          sum(b.item_quantity) as total_quantity, 
          sum(b.unit_price*item_quantity) as total_price
     from material_inventory as a inner join orders as b 
     on a.product_id = b.product.id
     group by a.product_id
) as x
```

Answer (score 0):

I would lay out my table like this...

Table `products`:

```
id | name | type | current_price
```

Table `orders`:

```
id | user_id | submitted
```

Table `order_items`:

```
id | order_id | product_id | locked_in_price | quantity
```

Set up this way, you can set `locked_in_price` to the product's `current_price` when it's first added to the cart. Then to get your items and the total, you would do this...

```
SELECT *, SUM(locked_in_price * quantity) AS total FROM order_items WHERE order_id = 1;
```